# Program works fine with small arrays, but it is suspended when the arrays get larger. How to allocate memory to large arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I'll explain my code first before going into my question in more details.

The program will continue to count the next number until the *n*th number is generated, and then print out that number.

Here's how it works.

With a given sequence of starting numbers, for example, 0,3,6

1. The 1st number is 0.
2. The 2nd number is 3.
3. The 3rd number is 6.
4. Now, consider the last number, 6. Since that was the first
   time the number had been spoken, the 4th number spoken is 0.

   (if the last number has  been spoken before, then, the next number
   is the difference between the turn number when it was last spoken
   and the turn number of the time it was most recently spoken before
   then. )
5. since the last number, which is the 4th number (0) has been
   spoken before, the most recent place where 0 appears before the last
   number is turn 1. Therefore, the 5th number is 4 - 1, which is 3.

...keep counting until the ***n*th** number.

My code works fine when n is 2022, but the program stop running when n = 30,000,000

The is how I allocate memory to my arrays

`int *test_case_one = new int[30000000];`

Below is my entire code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void test_cases( int Array[]);
int isfound( int table[], int current, int range);
int main() 
{
    int *test_case_one = new int[30000000];

    test_case_one[0] = 1;
    test_case_one[1] = 3;
    test_case_one[2] = 2;
    test_cases(test_case_one);

    delete[] test_case_one;
}

void test_cases( int Array[])
{
    int *table = new int[30000000];
    int turn;
    int last;
    table[0] = Array[0];
    table[1] = Array[1];
    table[2] = Array[2];
    table[3] = 0;
    
    for ( int i = 4; i < 30000000; i++)
    {
        last = table[i -1];
        turn = isfound(table, last, i);
        if ( turn != -1) {
            table[i] = (i-1) - turn;
        }
        else {
            table[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    cout<< table[29999999] << endl;
    delete[] table;
}

int isfound( int table[], int last, int range)
{
    for ( int j = range-1; j > 0 ; j--)  {
        if ( last == table[j -1]) {
            return (j - 1);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

How can I fix this memory overload issue?

Comment: Assuming your `int` is 32 bits on your machine, you're allocating a mere 240 MB of memory in total (30 million ints, twice). That's less than Chrome uses for a single tab. Your issue probably lies elsewhere. What does "stop running" means? Do you have an error? What is your debugger telling you?

Comment: By "stop running" I mean the program is suspending on the terminal window, I never get any output nor a single error.

Comment: Then maybe your algorithm is inefficient (in fact, pretty sure it is O(n^2)), and is therefore simply taking a long time with larger arrays. You never print anything between the start or the end of the program, so a slow execution will look like it's "frozen".

Comment: @Etienne de Martel I see, any hints on how to improve my algorithm?

Comment: It's worthwhile to watch your CPU usage (via `top` on Linux or `Activity Monitor` on MacOS or `Task Manager` on Windows or etc) while your program is running, to see if one of your cores goes to 100% during your program's execution.  If so, that's a good indication that your program is just taking a long time to execute its computations (as opposed to being hung/suspended somehow, which wouldn't cause it to use up lots of CPU cycles)

Answer (score 2):

You should not build a table of the values, but a table of last rank per value, initialized to 0. That way when you get a value, you have a direct access to next value and you algo become simply linear.

If you are sure that none of the initialization values will be greater than the expected number of iterations, then everything is fine because as other values will be index differences, this will also be less than that number.

Here is a simple code for your 0-3-6 example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int number;
    std::cout << "Total number (>=7): ";
    std::cin >> number;
    if (!std::cin || number < 5) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    // 3 initial values are 0, 3, 6, so 4th will be 0
    int* data = new int[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) data[i] = 0;
    data[0] = 1;
    data[3] = 2;
    int val = 6;
    for (int index = 3; index <= number; index++) {
        int newval = data[val] ? index - data[val] : 0;
        data[val] = index;
        val = newval;
        // uncomment next line to see intermediary values
        //printf("%d: %d\n", index + 1, val);
    }
    delete[] data;                 // always release dynamic objects...
    printf("Final %d: %d\n", number, val);
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, in modern C++ you should rarely directly allocate a raw array with new, precisely because if you do, you will be responsible for its deletion. It is much more common and easy to use standard containers, here a `std::vector`. (Thanks to @EtiennedeMartel for the remark).

Comment: While we're at it, I'd recommend using `std::vector` for the data, then you wouldn't have to worry about releasing it.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: you are right, and specially for beginners, even if here a raw array is enough. As an old C programmer I may too easily use C idioms, simply changing `malloc-free` into `new-delete`...

Comment: Using a vector instead of a dynamically allocated array has no drawback in any circumstance and has substantial benefits. I recommend it even for non beginners.

Comment: Thank you so much! I went through your code with all the test cases, and I found one error? in your second for loop. It should be ````index < number```` not ````index <= number````, otherwise, it won’t give me the correct answer, don’t know why that happens.